# Check for session in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core

Access to Session property of context raises exception because session is not configured.

How to detect if Session is available if it can be on or off depending on config.

In other words I cannot do this: `context.Session?.Clear();`

Comment: Are you not running `services.UseSession()` based on the config?

Comment: I assume you try to suggest to get it directly from config.. to be honest config is not the thing which I really have... I just said about config to explain that Session is optional... In reality reason is a bit different... Session can be used later.. but code should consider it already now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the safest and most performant way would be to use [request features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/request-features). For example, here's a simple extension method to get the session or null if it's not enabled:

```
public static ISession SafeSession(this HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var sessionFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<ISessionFeature>();
    return sessionFeature == null ? null : httpContext.Session;
}
```

Example usage from an MVC controller:

```
var session = this.HttpContext.SafeSession();
```

Comment: Yes, I agree.. at least it is what I am trying to do now.. )) I think you are right and we can accept this answer. Also I think you could update it to "this.HttpContext" to clarify it is instance (even syntax highlighting thinks wrong).

Comment: Well I was assuming this method was in a controller, perhaps even in a base controller class to give easy access across all of them. In fact, it probably may work better as an extension method...

Answer (score 0):

A hacky workaround, however might suffice to let you continue working until a better solution is found.

```
public class Startup
{
    public static bool IsSessionAvailable { get; set; }
    //...

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        IsSessionAvailable = false; // session not available

    //...
```

And then in your controller.

```
if (Startup.IsSessionAvailable)
{
    HttpContext.Session.Clear();
}
```